After importing the Facebook SDK into Unity, some errors appeared when packing the APK using Gradle
I was able to successfully build the Android package without importing the Facebook SDK. However, after importing the Facebook SDK, I encountered a "Build failed" issue when attempting to build the package. The version of the Facebook SDK I am using is 17.0.0, and the Gradle version is 7.2. Below are the specific details of the bug that occurred：

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

UnityEditor.GenericMenu:CatchMenu (object,string[],int)




FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':launcher:classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1/gradle-7.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1/gradle-7.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :launcher

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEditor.GenericMenu:CatchMenu (object,string[],int)



CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
D:\unity\2021.3.33f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "D:\SDK\gradle-7.2-all\gradle-7.2\lib\gradle-launcher-7.2.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"



Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 201 seconds (200656 ms)

UnityEditor.GenericMenu:CatchMenu (object,string[],int)



UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <06837d428b6d46f581d93f9597703696>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <06837d428b6d46f581d93f9597703696>:0 
UnityEditor.GenericMenu:CatchMenu (object,string[],int)



I have tried cleaning the cache and upgrading to the latest version of Gradle, but neither of these solutions has resolved the issue.

7.1 is an non-existent version of com.android.tools.build:gradle, change it to 7.1.2 in the build.gradle file (or in the baseProjectTemplate.gradle template file)

Pro!A new issue has emerged.

Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
You can try some of the following options:
- changing the IDE settings.
- changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
- changing org.gradle.java.home in gradle.properties.


Upgrade Java to 11

Thank you,pro.Currently, when I download the JDK 11 installation package from the official website and double-click it, nothing happens. Additionally, when I try to install JDK using other methods such as the scoop command line, I always encounter errors. Do you have any solutions?

What went wrong:
Value 'D:Scoopappsopenjdk11current' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)

